# javascript addEventListener without selecting children

Tags: javascript, events

I *need* to use javascript only for this project. Sorry, no jQuery (I feel ashamed as well).

I am adding an `addEventListener` to a div. "Problem" is that it applies to all its children, too.

Is there a way to avoid this, and have the listener work only for that div?

Thankd in advance.

---

my code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById(myObj.id).addEventListener("mousedown", myObjDown, false);

function myObjDown() {
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: It's not actually adding the event to the children (I'm guessing, since you haven't shown us code). What's happening is the event is bubbling. You want to bind the event in the capturing phase and cancel the bubbling. `element1.addEventListener('click',doSomething,true);` and `event.cancelBubble = true;`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can tell which element the event actually fired on by reading `event.target` in your callback.

```
var el = ...
el.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (el !== event.target) return;

  // Do your stuff.

}, false);
```

The other option would be to have handlers bound to the child elements to prevent the event from reaching the parent handler, but that is more work and potentially hides events from things that might actually be listening for them above the parent.

#### Update

Given your example code, you should be able to do this.

```
var el = document.getElementById(myObj.id);
el.addEventListener("mousedown", myObjDown, false);

function myObjDown(event) {
  if (el !== event.target) return;

  //do stuff here
}
```

Also as a general note, keep in mind that none if this will work on IE < 9 because `addEventListener` is not supported on those.

Comment: please take a look at my edit so you understand how I structured it

Comment: Thanks. I know about the IE thing, it's just that I need to use really simple javascript as per client request. -.- booring

Comment: @johnsmith It's not that bad. I do standard JS all day long :D

Answer (score 22):

You can use the currentTarget Event Property

```
el.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget !== event.target) {
    return;
  }

  // Do your stuff.
}, false);
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative, which keeps your myObjDown function in line with a typical event handler. (using e.target as reference to the event invoking element)

```
var CssSelector = "div.className";
var elms = document.querySelectorAll(CssSelector);

for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].addEventListener("mousedown", myObjDown.bind(null, {"target":elms[i]}, false);
}

function myObjDown(e) {
  console.log("event: %o - target: %o", e, e.target);

  var elm = e.target;
  //do stuff here
}
```

---

### It was suggested that ..

this method could cause memory leaks with versions of some browsers. If anyone experiences this or has any valuable insights. Please comment.

---

### an alternative, in this regard would be

```
var CssSelector = "div.className";
var elms = document.querySelectorAll(CssSelector);

for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    elms[i].addEventListener("mousedown", myObjDown.bind(null, elms[i].id}, false);
}

function myObjDown(id) {
  console.log("element: %o ", document.getElementById(id));

  //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
document.getElementById(myObj.id).addEventListener("mousedown", myObjDown, false);

    function myObjDown(e) {
    
     var myTarget= ele.target;  
     while (myTarget!== this) { 
        myTarget= myTarget.parentNode;    //finding correct tag
     }
    
      //do stuff here
    }
```