# how to removeeventlistener from child elements (inside a loop)?

Tags: javascript

a click event is heard by a div with elements inside, so when you click on the elements inside the div the addEventListener function is also activated and I would like the elements inside not to listen to it, some of these elements are paragraphs, inputs or texts that are inside the div.

I have tried using event target and removeeventlistener, without success

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>

        .frame {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: brown;
        }
        input {
            margin: auto;
        }
        p {
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frame">
    
    <input placeholder="same effect here">
    <p>CLICK DIV</p>
    
</div>

<div class="frame">
    
    <input placeholder="same effect here">
    <p>CLICK DIV</p>
    
</div>

<div class="frame">
    
    <input placeholder="same effect here">
    <p>CLICK DIV</p>
    
</div>
</body>
```

```html
<script>
  const labels = document.querySelectorAll(".frame");

  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; ++i) {
    labels[i].addEventListener("click", function touch() {
      // resize div
      if (this.clientWidth == 200) {
        this.style.width = "400px";
        this.style.height = "400px";
      } else {
        this.style.width = "200px";
        this.style.height = "200px";
      }

      //remove the event
      this.firstElementChild.removeEventListener("click", touch);

      //document.querySelectorAll('input').removeEventListener('click', touch);
    });
  }
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wooddocu/Lsfocjpe/5/)

Comment: From the duplicate, I prefer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30524763/283366)

Comment: Phil and how do I use remove? the question says how to use removeeventlistener, not event.target or currentTarget

Comment: You don't need to. The event listener isn't added to the child elements so there's nothing to remove. The issue is that events bubble up the document hierarchy. If you check that `e.target === e.currentTarget` in the event handler, you know the event originated on the `<div>` and not one of its children

Comment: Here's a demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/gv0tce42/

Comment: Phil and how can i use event target without using an If conditional? I already said try to use event target without success

Comment: Does the demo not show you how? Why would you not want to use an `if`?

Comment: Phil I want to select the descendant elements that listen or not, they can be few or many

Comment: there are thousands of divs with hundreds of different descendant elements inside

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What does selecting the child elements have to do with your question about removing event listeners? You can simply use `this.querySelectorAll("p")` for example to select the `<p>` tags within the clicked `<div>`

Comment: Phil and how can I make some or all of the descendant elements listen or not, with this.querySelector("") for labels? it looks like document.querySelectorAll('input').removeEventListener('click', touch) I already said to use it and it is in the code of the question

Comment: i simply want to select with removeeventlistener the listeners. Can be used yes or no?